# Create a shipping method for free items on woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking to create two separate shipping sets based on items that are in the cart.
I want free shipping on shipping class "holiday packages" and free shipping on product category "coffee" when there are more than 2 bags of coffee in the cart. Then I want the rest of the items to be put into a different shipping "container".

I currently can get it all to work when there are two different coffees in there (thus is up ticking the coffee count) but when there are two of one type of coffee it doesn't separate it.

```
/* Puts items with "holiday-package" shipping class into a different shipping package. */
 function hdm_woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages( $packages ) {

     // Reset the packages
     $packages = array();

     // Free items
     $freeshipping_items = array();
     $regular_items      = array();
     $coffee_count = 0;
     //get product category and count up each item in that category

     foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
       $quantity = $item['quantity'];
      if ($item['data']->get_shipping_class() == 'coffee') {
          $coffee_count++; }
      elseif ($quantity >= 2 && $item['data']->get_shipping_class() == 'coffee') {
          $coffee_count = 2;
          }
    }

     // Sort free from regular.
     foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
         if( $item['data']->needs_shipping() ) {
             if( $item['data']->get_shipping_class() == 'holiday-packages' ) {
                 $freeshipping_items[] = $item;
             }
             elseif ($item['data']->get_shipping_class() == 'coffee' && $coffee_count >= 2){
               $freeshipping_items[] = $item;
             }
             else {
                 $regular_items[] = $item;
             }
         }
     }

     // Put inside packages:
     if( $regular_items ) {
         $packages[] = array(
             'ship_via'        => array(),
             'contents'        => $regular_items,
             'contents_cost'   => array_sum(wp_list_pluck($regular_items, 'line_total')),
             'applied_coupons' => WC()->cart->applied_coupons,
             'destination'     => array(
                 'country'   => WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(),
                 'state'     => WC()->customer->get_shipping_state(),
                 'postcode'  => WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode(),
                 'city'      => WC()->customer->get_shipping_city(),
                 'address'   => WC()->customer->get_shipping_address(),
                 'address_2' => WC()->customer->get_shipping_address_2()
             )
         );
     }
     if( $freeshipping_items ) {
         $packages[] = array(
             'ship_via'        => array( 'flat_rate' ),
             'contents'        => $freeshipping_items,
             'contents_cost'   => array_sum(wp_list_pluck($freeshipping_items, 'line_total')),
             'applied_coupons' => WC()->cart->applied_coupons,
             'destination'     => array(
                 'country'   => WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(),
                 'state'     => WC()->customer->get_shipping_state(),
                 'postcode'  => WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode(),
                 'city'      => WC()->customer->get_shipping_city(),
                 'address'   => WC()->customer->get_shipping_address(),
                 'address_2' => WC()->customer->get_shipping_address_2()
             )
         );
     }

     return $packages;
 }

 add_filter('woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages', 'hdm_woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages');
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I was about to fix it by changing

```
  elseif ($quantity >= 2 && $item['data']->get_shipping_class() == 'coffee') {
      $coffee_count = 2;
      }
```

to

```
  if ($quantity >= 2 && $item['data']->get_shipping_class() == 'coffee') {
      $coffee_count = 2;
      }
```

I don't think it will come up with the correct quantities, but it works for my needs. If anyone has any advice on how to better write this it would be much appreciated.